# Evaluate $\int_{\gamma} \frac{2 \sin(z) +e^z}{z^2 - 2z} dz$ where $\gamma = C(0,3)$ with positive orientation.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> I need to evaluate $\int_{\gamma} \frac{2 \sin(z) +e^z}{z^2 - 2z} dz$ where $\gamma = C(0,3)$ with positive orientation.

We know that:
$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{2 \sin(z) +e^z}{z^2 - 2z} dz = 2 \int_{\gamma} \frac{ \sin(z)}{z^2 - 2z} dz + \int_{\gamma} \frac{e^z}{z^2 - 2z} dz = 2 \int_{\gamma} \frac{ \sin(z)}{z(z - 2)} dz + \int_{\gamma} \frac{e^z}{z(z - 2)} dz$$

To evaluate $2\int_{\gamma} \frac{ \sin(z)}{z(z-2)} dz$ we take:

$$2\int_{\gamma} \frac{ \sin(z)}{z(z-2)} dz = 2 \int_{\gamma_1} \dfrac{ \sin(z)/z}{(z-2)}dz +  2\int_{\gamma_2} \dfrac{ \sin(z)/\{z-2\}}{z}dz $$
Where $\gamma_1$ is a circle around pole $z = 2$ and $\gamma_2$ is a circle around pole $z = 0$.
Using Cauchy's Integral Formula:
$$2 \int_{\gamma_1} \dfrac{ \sin(z)/z}{(z-2)}dz = 2 * 2 \pi i \frac{ \sin(2)}{2} = 2 \pi i \sin(2)$$
$$2\int_{\gamma_2} \dfrac{ \sin(z)/\{z-2\}}{z}dz = 2 * 2 \pi i \frac{ \sin(0)}{-2} = 0$$

To evaluate $\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^z}{z(z - 2)} dz$ we take:

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^z}{z(z - 2)} dz = \int_{\gamma_1} \dfrac{e^z/z}{(z-2)}dz + \int_{\gamma_2} \dfrac{e^z/\{z-2\}}{z}dz $$
Where $\gamma_1$ is a circle around pole $z = 2$ and $\gamma_2$ is a circle around pole $z = 0$.

Using Cauchy's Integral Formula:
$$\int_{\gamma_1} \dfrac{e^z/z}{(z-2)}dz = 2 \pi i \frac{e^2}{2} = \pi i e^2$$
$$\int_{\gamma_2} \dfrac{e^z/\{z-2\}}{z}dz = 2 \pi i \frac{e^0}{-2} = -\pi i$$

Taking everything together we get:
$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{2 \sin(z) +e^z}{z^2 - 2z} dz = 2 \pi i \sin(2) + \pi i e^2 -\pi i$$

Is that correct? I did it just by looking in the textbook and examples so it may be all wrong.

Comment: What does $S(0,3)$ denote?

Comment: Circle with center at $0$ and radius $3$. I changed that to $C(0,3)$ to be more intuitive.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

While evaluating $\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{\sin z/z}{z-2}dz$ using Cauchy integral formula, the assumption $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ must be analytic within and on $\gamma_1$ must hold. You can see that $z=0$ is a removable singularity of $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ and defining $f(0)=1$ is required there; so the application of formula is not as trivial and needs some background assumptions and theorems like *analytic continuation*. Though **Cauchy's Residue Theorem** gives you the correct result without using deformation principle.